# Pom version change command for modules?

Tags: maven

I have pom_test.xml(not pom.xml) parent pom. The command for changing parent pom version is

```
mvn versions:set - DnewVersion=version - f pom_test.xml
```

However, above command does not change the version of the module poms(which are also pom_test.xml) in this parent pom.

How can i change their versions also?

Comment: Why not using the defaults `pom.xml`? What is the reason for having a different named pom file? Can you show an example of your project structure?

Comment: I am not using the original pom because we are testing and does not want to modify original pom during testing. About project structure, I have pom_test.xml in same folder as pom

Comment: Does not make sense. You should use your version control system via a branch....